# How to get the original source code of a webpage in android

Tags: android, httpclient

I am able to get the source code of a webpage in android using HTTPClient , but the android's webpage source code is different while compared to computer's one. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but the android's webpage source code is different while compared to computer's one. How to resolve this?

Set `User-Agent` header something that desktop browsers sends, that should trick server to believe request is coming from desktop and if there are different versions of the site, desktop one should be served:

```
var ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Horst NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0" 
var client = new HttpClient()
client.DefaultRequestHeaders
        .Add("User-Agent", ua)
```

Also see this document: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent/Firefox

This is not 100% bullet proof as it may fail if server is using other ways to guess who is requesting, but it's simplest one and would be perfectly sufficient in most cases.

**EDIT**

> I have used the HTTPClient like HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

Then add `setHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, ua)` to your chain before `build()`:

```
HttpClientBuilder.create()
    .setHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, ua)
    .build();
```

Comment: I have used the HTTPClient like `HttpClient httpClient =  HttpClientBuilder.create().build();` . So i am not able to resolve DefaultRequestHeaders.

Comment: Then add `.setHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, ua)` to your chain before `build()`

Comment: what's a Windows [Horst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horst_(given_name))?

Comment: No idea. I copied some random UA string from (AFAIR) Mozilla website. May be typo. Irrelevant in context for the OP question though

Comment: setHeader doesn't work in HttpClientBuilder. Instead had to use 
`HttpClient httpClient =  HttpClientBuilder.create().setUserAgent(ua).build();`